# Cron job scheduled to open terminal window results in error

Tags: linux, cron

I am running Amazon Linux.
I have crontab setup as follows.

`* * * * * mate-terminal -e run.sh >> output.log 2>&1`

I get the following error in the output file.
`Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:`

My objective is to have cron open a new terminal window and run a script inside of it.

I have tried the following:

- Running the cron on current user and sudo
- Removing the script to be run `* * * * * mate-terminal >> output.log 2>&1`

I get the same error in output file for all attempts.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The mate-terminal needs to know which display to open the terminal on.
There is a reasonable chance that you want to use display 0, but you should use

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

in a terminal on your desired display. Then set your crontab entry to something like

```
* * * * * mate-terminal -display :0 -e run.sh >> output.log 2>&1
```

replacing the `:0` with the output from the echo.

Comment: Should the display be preceded by two dashes, ```--display```?

Comment: X programs tend to predate the convention that long options start with two dashes, so usually only want one.

Answer (score 1):

Do you **really** want to have a cron job pop up a screen on your UI? Or do you just want to run `run.sh`?

If you want to the job to pop up the terminal, then you have to specify where it should be displayed with the `--display` option, for example. That might not be enough though, because `cron` runs a certain user, that might or not have access to your display.

If you just want to run the command, this would probably do (you might need to change the shell, depending on `run.sh`)

```
* * * * * /bin/sh -e /full/path/to/run.sh >> /full/path/to/output.log 2>&1
```

Note the full paths to files and script.